# How double negation in problem from Ken Rosen's Discrete Math exercise "an explorer captured by a group of two cannibals" work?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

There is a puzzle in the book  [Discrete Mathematics and its applications](https://www.houstonisd.org/cms/lib2/TX01001591/Centricity/Domain/26781/DiscreteMathematics.pdf)  Page 23 - Exercise 16 . Puzzle goes like -
"An Explorer captured by a group of two cannibals. There are two type of cannibals-those who always tell the truth and those who always lie. The cannibals will barbecue the explorer unless he can determine whether a particular cannibal always lies or always tells the truth. He is allowed to ask the cannibal exactly one question.
Find the question that the explorer can use to determine whether the cannibal always lies or always tells the truth."

I know some solutions like you can ask cannibals "are you a cannibal", "is the colour of sky is blue?". But that is not how logic works right?
There is another solution which is perfect. Solution is, you ask cannibal "If I were to ask you if you are a liar, would you answer 'Yes'?"
Truther cannibal will answer "No" because he is not a liar.
But I don't know what Liar cannibal will answer. Will he also answer "No" because he always lies?
And I want to know how double Negation is working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it into parts.
The liar cannibal will always say the wrong answer. When you ask him "If I were to ask you if you are a liar, would you answer 'Yes'?" he answers the opposite.
The liar cannibal thinks for himself: "If I was asked if I am a liar, would I answer 'Yes'?" Because he is a liar, if he was asked, he would answer 'No, I am not a liar'. But that not you asked him. You asked "**If I were to ask you**". So the liar would lie about that too- instead of saying 'No, I am not al liar' he would say "**Yes**, If I was asked if I am a liar I would answer 'Yes'".

The double negation is something like this:

> `not` (if I was asked: `not` (am I a liar?))

"am I a liar?" is `true` so (`not` (am I a liar?)) is `false`. Because of that the whole statement is `true`.

Hope it was clear :) This is indeed a tricky question.

Comment: Ah okay.. So because he is a liar he will lie that "No, I am not a liar". But because he is a liar he will lie about his own lie, Am I right? Ughh my brain is totally messed up. I know its simple question for most of you but I am dumb lol.

Comment: Imagine the liar thinks what the right answer is and just says the opposite. If you would ask him if he were a liar, he would say no. So, he would say the opposite when you ask him the whole question.

Comment: Okay... Finally I understood it. Thanks for the clarification buddy.

Answer (score 0):

If you asked the straightforward question "Are you a liar?" then a Truther cannibal would truthfully answer No, but a Liar would also answer No and you couldn't tell them apart.

Your "question within a question" query would work though. If you asked one of the cannibals "If I were to ask you if you are a liar, would you answer 'Yes'?", the Truther cannibal will still truthfully answer No, but a Liar would lie about lying and answer Yes.

---

Side note: It's good to see schools are still teaching from Rosen's *Discrete Math*. It's by far one of my favorite text books.

Comment: But how liar will say "Yes"? He is a liar so he should answer "No". And how he will lie about lying ? Can you please explain it in detail?. Btw School is not teaching us from this book, I started reading this book to learn logics.

Comment: @RudraSama The liar would respond Yes to the second question because you're asking about their response to the first question. Since they would have lied and answered No in the first case, they'd lie about lying in the second case and say Yes.